# Regex to capture multiple groups of SELECT queries in a single statement with 0 or more UNIONs?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a list of SQL queries which can range from a simple

> **SELECT * from** ABC

to complex ones like

> **SELECT A,B,C from** ABC Where Z=5 and T=10 UNION **SELECT * from** GHI Where i=100 UNION **SELECT X,Y from** XYZ

I would like to capture the bold sections using a regex. Currently, I have `(SELECT[\s]*.*from[\s]*)` but this treats the 2nd query as a single SELECT query i.e. `SELECT .... from XYZ` while I need it to find 3 parts highlighted above.

Can someone pls kindly offer some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Make the repetition not greedy. Aka add a question mark `[\s]*?`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I've improved formatting of your post for you. Please be careful with formatting next time since it makes a big deal of how easily the post is read. Please always format you code as code (with backticks or 4-space indentation); here I used a quotation syntax since you wanted to highlight some parts of the strings. Please also keep in mind that new paragraph starts after *double* linebreak (you can also add 2 spaces in the end of the line to add `<br>`)

Comment: Also, since you're asking about regexes, you should point *which language you are using*. You should always point the desired and the actual behaviour (I've improved wording in the edit). Finally, please take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read some https://stackoverflow.com/help about asking so that you can ask questions which are answered with pleasure and are helpful for others. Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern should work in pretty much any language in case-insensitive mode:

```
SELECT\s(?:(?!FROM)[\s\S])*\sFROM
```

This even works when the SQL code spreads across multiple lines.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/sBJTpF/1)

Alternatively, enable single-line mode and just use a dot: `SELECT\s(?:(?!FROM).)*\sFROM`.